# Строка как условие python

Tags: python, if

если возможность задавать условие оператору IF другим условным оператором IF?

```
    if fotel.isdigit() == True:
        findzn = 'fotel[-10:].find(tel[-10:])>-1'
    else:
        findzn = 'SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x==" ", fotel, gosno).ratio > 0.8'
    if (findzn) :
        .........
```

Что-то типа этого. Необходимо для поиска в базе данных в зависимости от их типа.

Comment: Уберите кавычки, и получите вполне рабочий код, по крайней мере для этого конкретного примера.

Comment: Точно сработет если убрать кавычки